# Control Failing To Enter The Method when Dynamically generated Buttons are clicked in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, button

I am sorry for weird title. I am dealing with dynamic generation of Ui components. I have a ListBox in my Xaml class which generates the buttons dynamically.

**View:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="SetButtonList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate >
                     <Grid>                                   
                         <Button Content="{Binding Path=SetButtonFreq}" Command="{Binding Path=SetFreqCommand}" />                                    
                     </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ICommand mSetFreqCommand;
public ICommand SetFreqCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSetFreqCommand == null)
                mSetFreqCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(SetFreqCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(SetFreqCommandCanExecute));

            return mSetFreqCommand;
        }
        set;            
    }

    public bool SetFreqCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void SetFreqCommandExecuted()
    {
        // Executes the Body when Button is Clicked
    }
```

**Model:**

```
private string _SetFreqValue = "";
public String SetButtonFreq
    {
        set; get;            
    }

    public ClockModel(string SetButtonFreq)
    {
        this.SetButtonFreq = SetButtonFreq;
    }        

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _SetFreqValue;
    }
```

**View.cs file:**

```
// mClock is object of Model Class
mClock.Add(new ClockModel("Set 12.0 MHz"));
mClock.Add(new ClockModel("Set 12.288 MHz"));
mClock.Add(new ClockModel("Set 15.36 MHz"));
mClock.Add(new ClockModel("Set 19.2 MHz"));
```

This gives me 4 buttons with different frequencies in my listbox. But when I try to Click them the control doesn't enter the `SetFreqCommandExecuted()` method. Where am i making a mistake? :(

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button tries to find **SetFreqCommand** inside the bound item, not in your general **ViewModel** for current page. You may fix it with this binding:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=SetButtonList, Path=DataContext.SetFreqCommand}"
```

Comment: @Nagg: No brother. It's not working. looks like something is wrong with PATH since its been used both at Content & Command.

Comment: @StonedJesus: Nagg explanation is correct. Both answers were more or less the same, hence why I deleted mine. Try with `Path=DataContext.SetFreqCommand` instead. Additionally, have a look at the Output window in Visual Studio when debugging: binding errors are shown here.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain: Ur first comment did the job :) Thanks a lot Julien and Nagg :)